# Infinity - number = infinity

Tags: javascript, math, subtraction

In javascript `Infinity - 100` results in `Infinity` which makes sense,
but the resulted Infinity does not appear to be less than the initial Infinity like in real math.

I am trying to sort some array, and items from array that don't have a certain property are assigned a default Infinity value, then sorting should fallback to Infinity minus a different property. The problem is that this subtraction does not produce different Infinity values.

Comment: maybe use MAX_SAFE_INTEGER?

Comment: There is no such thing `different Infinity values`  in `math`.

Comment: Use a number larger than your working set

Comment: Why don't you use [quick sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/) algo?

Comment: Usually, in math, infinity > n, n ∈ R. Infinity is not a real number, so two infinities are not comparable.

Comment: Sort pairs of (number,boolean) (or boolean in another array and sort indirectly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to think of Infinity as a number. Infinity minus a finite number is still (the same) Infinity, it's math theory.
That's why you get that result.

Comment: Reminder: You should not use specification in JS for math definition. The [specification of infinity in js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity) is slightly different from maths.

Comment: @ikhvjs Sorry, I don't see how your comment is related to the answer.

Comment: It is a reminder to people when they try to apply the math definition to specification of a programming language. This may lead to some misunderstanding for other programming problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Infinity means the number which you can't define/count. So if you minus some value won't affect the infinity. Still that infinite value is undefinable/Uncounted.
Hence the answer would still be Infinity.